# Image not Displaying even though path is correct

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I'm working with .NET Maui for the first time, and I already have problems with the Image. So when starting the default page, there is this robot image. I put another image into the /Image folder, and replaced it with the robot image in the `xaml` file.

I added this to my page:

```
            <Image Source="Logo.png"
                   WidthRequest="250"
                   HeightRequest="250"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
```

But the image is not displayed on the page, the place where the image is is just blank. I don't know what I did wrong, because everyone said that it should work if the filename is correct, and the Image is in the right folder.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the image in the `/Resources/Images` folder?

Comment: and does it have the correct build action?

Comment: The build action should be `Maui image`. You can find the build action when you right click on the image in the solution explorer and then click on `properties`.

Comment: Images are stored with no capital letters , Source="logo.png"

Comment: @BasH, from examples I've seen, that Xamarin.Forms limitation may have been removed for Maui. But it is worth trying, if nothing else works.

Comment: As I tried in .net maui, the image would not display if there were capital letters in image names.

Answer (score 0):

From [Image / Load a local image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/image?view=net-maui-7.0#load-a-local-image):

> Images can be added to your app project by dragging them to the **Resources\Images** folder of your project, **where its build action will automatically be set to MauiImage.**

Sometimes it is necessary to **Close Solution**, then re-open it, for VS to update its list of included images.

This is the line in `.csproj` that "automatically" sets build action for all images in folder `Resources\Images`:

```xml
<MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
```